# Is there a way to completely remove the keyboard layout from the indicator?

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, indicator, gnome-panel, keyboard-layout

I need to completely remove the indicator, no flags, no abbr. nothing!
I was able to do it in 10.04 using a gconf key that has no scheme and I heard that a proper scheme will be available in 10.10 but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/631989)

the key I was talking about is:

`gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/general/disable_indicator -t bool true`

For pre-maverick only.

Thank you all for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Press Alt+F2 and enter [`gconf-editor`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor)

Now navigate to apps-->gnome_settings_daemon-->plugins-->keyboard and uncheck active

Restart.

Comment: While it deactivates the indicator indeed, I can't switch layouts anymore (Alt+shift).

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you're removing it because of the big ugly (redundant) image in the 10.10 keyboard indicator, I've got a solution to that. I created a set of SVG flag images. If you install them and activate "show flags" in your g-conf editor then the text and ugly image both disappear. In their place you just have the one (much smaller) input language flag. I've posted the SVG's and full instructions here: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Faenza+and+Elementary?content=133726

Comment: This entry would be a nice comment to the question but this is not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already saw your work, I don't want anything there plus you didn't include Arabic, otherwise I'll use it.

Comment: Actually, I've fixed the flag sets to include several other language, including Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

I have completely same task, and i have just solve it for myself by using icons with the sizes of 1px * 1px, this is not completely removal, but it's best solution i could found.

Steps:
1) download icons (for example from [here](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Language+Flags+for+Faenza+and+Elementary?content=133726))

2)Untar (expand) the downloaded file into the folder ~/.icons/flags. If there is no "flags" sub-folder just create it. Then you need to enable the display of flags for input languages in gconf:

3) Open gconf-editor (in Ubuntu type ALT-F2 to open the "run application" dialogue and then type "gconf-editor" without the quotes and press enter).

4) Navigate the folder tree to Desktop > Gnome > Peripherals > Keyboard > Indicator

5) Activate the check-box for "showFlags"

6) Find icons for your languages in folder ~/.icons/flags, for me it was us.svg and ru.svg. Open it in image editor like Inkscape, and resize to 1*1 px (in inkscape Shift+Ctrl+D), save it.

Comment: Nice hack, I currently use Faenza-Dark indicator icons, which comes with a nice keyboad icon.